# What is analogous to the Windows registry in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, windows, settings

I am new to Mac and was wondering where application/OS settings are saved.

Comment: You would be surprised how many apps on OS X are self-contained. Drag drop them out of your /Applications/ folder onto another machine, and you'll find most of them run fine -- try that on Windows :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For typical macOS applications the place for this kind of information is one of

- `/System/Library` (for OS specific stuff)
- `/Library` (for system-wide preferences/settings valid for all users)
- `~/Library` (for user-specific preferences/settings)

and the folders beneath them (e.g. `Application Support` and `Preferences`).

They are saved as individual files, usually named so you can identify them and with a structure which is (at least most of the time) understandable by mere humans. Most of these files are Property List files ending in `.plist` which can be pretty-printed into a human-readable form by running `plutil -p NAME-OF-FILE.plist` in Terminal.

For applications and binaries coming from the Unix world you‘ll also find the typical dot files and directories in the home directory of all users using them, e.g. `.bashrc` or `.ssh/`. The names and purpose of these files is usually listed in the corresponding man page.